# Is LUIS limited for use?

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have been receiving exception in my application saying

```
Exception: Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Quota Exceeded).
```

Does this means we are only allowed 1000 hits per application per month on the LUIS?

Anyother justification are welcomed around this exceptions.

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/language-understanding-intelligent-services/

Comment: thank you @Sefa. this says 10,000 transactions free per month for free service. Do you know where I can track my transactions so far ?

Comment: There is also a quota per second, not explicit in the documentation but from my tests it was around 5 / second in a free plan

Comment: That's really weird. Assuming now per second transaction causing this. May need to check this on the paid plan. Thank you @NicolasR

Comment: I added an answer with the proof of this limit :)

Comment: Which route is it? I usually get 429.

Comment: 403 as per the stack trace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several quotas on LUIS's keys usage:

- Free key:
- 5 calls / second
- 10 000 calls / month
- Standard key:
- 50 calls / second

See Azure portal's capture below where the 5/second is visible for free plan:

[image: Azure capture]

And link to LUIS pricing [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/fr-fr/pricing/details/cognitive-services/language-understanding-intelligent-services/?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365)

Answer (score 0):

There is also (or was) an out of Azure preview key good for only 1000 messages per month on a rolling daily window.  Not sure if it’s still there but it could be what you’re running into.  It was called the bootstrap key and was just using your programmatic api key as the runtime key.

Answer (score 0):

It is also depending on the starter key that was created for each user when using LUIS free from first time, we need to migrate the luis model to a Azure resource, only then we can use 10,000 message free per month as per F0 plan, else it will be 1000 for each user authorizing key.

Reference link  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-keys